# How to add Clonezilla iso entry to grub?

Tags: grub, grub2, clonezilla

I would like to be able to boot into Clonezilla and backup/restore an entire partition/drive by using grub.

- I saw Phil Webster's suggestion [here](https://clonezilla.org/livehd.php), but I don't understand where I should place the iso file, and also the format suggested there for the `menuentry` doesn't look like `sh` syntax that I see inside `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

Comment: If your goal is to clone the same drive then you shouldn't use that method, you should always boot it from an external drive (USB or CD). Also cloning isn't a backup.

Comment: What do you mean by cloning isn't a backup?